# Property ownership data

Tags: city, real-estate, land

Is it generally considered open data who owns a given piece of property? I am looking at the [San Francisco Property Information Map](http://propertymap.sfplanning.org/) but it does not include any information about who owns a building, and it also includes several buildings in each search result.

Specifically, I'd like to generate a map of San Francisco by landlord, so anything that points me toward that direction would help.

Comment: You might want to check county or state records.  In Maryland, ownership records are maintained [at the state level](http://www.dat.state.md.us/sdatweb/real.html) for taxation purposes.  You'd also need ownership information if you were to ever try to sue the owner because of injury due to poor maintenance  (which is part of why buildings might be owned by different trusts/shell companies, which makes it more difficult to see if one person/group owns lots of buildings)

Answer (score 4):

The link below lists all SF municipal websites that provide public datasets related to property. I do not know if any of these datasets have ownership records.

http://propertymap.sfplanning.org/maphelp.html

I just found some more information from the city website sf311:
http://www.sf311.org/index.aspx?page=716

*Assessor-Recorder - Owner of Property in San Francisco - 106765
Question:
Who is the owner of a property in San Francisco?
Answer:
The San Francisco Assessor-Recorder's office maintains information on property ownership for properties located in San Francisco.
This information is not available online. You may get information by calling 554-5596 or by going to their office, Monday through Friday, between the hours of 8:00 a.m. – 5:00 p.m. They are located at City Hall, 1 Dr. Carlton B. Goodlett Place, Room 190, San Francisco, CA 94102.*

Comment: Links down.....

Answer (score 3):

Doubt you'll find it all in one place, without visiting a city office, but here's some help:
City Lots shapefiles
https://data.sfgov.org/Geographic-Locations-and-Boundaries/City-Lots-Zipped-Shapefile-Format-/3vyz-qy9p
San Francisco Housing Authority Lots
https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/san-francisco-housing-authority-parcels-9e921

Now you have all of the city lots in SF, you just need to know ownership. I'm assuming each has an id that can be mapped to an owner, but as for finding that file....good luck.
You can go ahead and lay the SFHA lots over the city lots, and then label those. At least its a start...

Comment: Links down.....

Comment: thats a bummer. its not been saved in the wayback machine either. searching sf housing authority site returns 0 results for parcels and 0 for data.